# How to repeat alarm in android 6.0

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using the `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` to set the alarm. But it works for only one time. How will I set the repeating alarm with interval 1 day? 
Before the API Level 23 `setInexactRepeating` method working fine.

Comment: It´s stated out in the api....you have to repeat the alarm manually. That means, if the alarm comes up, set the new alarm yourself like you did with the first one.

Comment: @Ankur Did you manage to get this done?

Comment: I am doing it the manual way. @devgeek

Comment: Can you please share how are you doing it in a manual way? @AnkurKhandelwal

Answer (score 2):

Recharge your alarm when you broadcast receiver event is executing.

I mean,

```
public class CustomBroadcast extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String somekey = "somekey.somekey.somekey";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(ctx.getPackageName(),
        YourSevice.class.getName());
        YourCustomClass.yourrechargefunction();
        startWakefulService(ctx, intent.setComponent(comp));
    }
}

public class YourCustomClass {
    private final static int somekey_int = anynumber;
    public static void yourrechargefunction() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CustomBroadcast.somekey):
        PendingIntent pi = wPendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx,somekey_int, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexttime, pi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**AlarmManager.setRepeating** doesn't work properly on different android versions.

Try **setExact**. It won't repeat but you can achieve repeating functionality as mentioned below:

**Updated AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("SERVICE_TEMPORARY_STOPPED"));

        long repeatCount = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getLong("REPEAT_COUNT", 0L);

        repeatCount++;

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (context).edit().putLong("REPEAT_COUNT", repeatCount).apply()

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (repeatCount *System.currentTimeMillis()),pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Here we maintain a repeatCount & variable (preference based) and increment it in your AlarmReceiver & schedule alarm again by calculating nextAlarmTime using repeatCount * System.currentTimeMillis();