# Starting alarm after specified days

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello Below is my **code** to Start the `alarm` in my application.

```
public static void startReferAlarm(Context context,String[] message,String activityToOpen) 
{
    try {

        Log.d("Refer friend Activity", "Alarm On");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("message",message);
        myIntent.putExtra("äctivityName",activityToOpen);

        final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent appIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, _id, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //48*60*60*1000

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                48*60*60*1000, appIntent);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

From my understating above code will start the alarm and will notify on **8 am.** and then will repeat after **48 hours**.

But I want to start the alarm after `48 hours` or lets say after `7 hours` and then it repeat after every `48 hours`.

Please help me with the logic.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to add time to the start time? Look at the `Calendar#add()` method.

Comment: Hey Mike. Nope. I am asking how to set the intial launch day and time. For example. I install the application but never created profile. So Application will wait for 7 days and then launch alarm asking user to create profile. and this alarm will repeat on alternate days on predefined time.

Comment: So, yes, then. You want to add 7 days to your current start time for the initial alarm.

Comment: Yes. I want to set 7 days interval for intial launch and then repeat it on alternate days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `calender.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8)` as it will set hours to 8'o clock

Try

```
//if you want to add 7 hours
calender.add(Calender.HOUR, 7); //this will add 7 hours to current time

//if you want to add 7 days
calender.add(Calender.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7); //this will add 7 days to current time

// interval to repeat alarm after 48hours
int interval = 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

Replace `Calendar.HOUR` with `Calendar.HOUR_OF_THE_DAY` if you want to use it in 24hours format.

See the answer for repeating alarm issue [How to repeat alarm in android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450427/how-to-repeat-alarm-in-android-6-0/43451214#43451214)

Comment: Hey thnx for hint. What about launching alarm after 7 days of app install and repeat it on alternate days. What we need to pass in calender.add() method.

Comment: Thnx. This is my code.
  calendar.add(DAY_OF_MONTH,7);  launch after 7 days.
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9); on that day it will intiate at 9 am in the morning 
  To repeate on 48 hours interval. alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    48*60*60*1000, createProfileAppIntent);

Answer (score 1):

For any one who is still confuse. Below method will initiate the alarm after 7 days of any particular action it will notify on 9 am and will repeat after 48 hours.

```
 public static void startCreateProfileAlarm(Context context,AlarmManager alarmManager ,String[] message,String activityToOpen) {

    try {

        //working code
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(DAY_OF_MONTH,7);
        //calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);

        // we can set any time here
        //calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("message",message);
        myIntent.putExtra("äctivityName",activityToOpen);


        final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

         createProfileAppIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        //48*60*60*1000
        //2*60*1000
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                48*60*60*1000, createProfileAppIntent);


    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```